# Using Netfilter, how would you block a local IP range?

Tags: filtering, netfilter

I understand how to drop certain packets containing x protocols but I'm wondering how I would go about blocking an IP range, or more specifically, a subnet?

My instinct is to use the netmask to to determine the subnet and then zero out anything beyond that, then compare it to the range I want blocked, then drop it if it matches. But there is no netmask in the header of a packet, so  this method won't work.

Has anyone done something similar? And if so, how did you accomplish this?

Comment: Just compare the IP to the range you want blocked?

Comment: Well, how would that work with 192.168.22.17 without a netmask? I don't know where the subnet begins

Comment: Don't know where the subnet ends and the host range begins*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You know what IP range you want to block, and you know the source IP of the packet. The source IP of other packets doesn't matter, just this one. If the source IP of the packet under inspection matches the range you've defined, drop it. I'm afraid I don't know netfilter at all and can't give an answer, I'm just trying to approach this from a high level. I'm not understanding why you need to know the subnet the sending machine is on.

Comment: Of course if you _don't_ know what IP range you want to block, then you can't do anything.